# How to remove one corner of a div

Tags: html, css

I have two containers, one with a red background, and one with a white background. The one with a white background partially overlaps the red one, and I would like to create the effect that you can see in the linked image. How can I do?

The final result should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiNe9.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```